# Core data subclass ManagedObject's to-many relationship addObject can't work

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsset

I have two subclass of ManagedObject as below

[image]

which is one-to-many relationship between them.

In order to add definition to word, I implement the func below:

```
func addDefinition(definition: MODefinition) {

    self.mutableSetValueForKey("definitions").addObject(definition)

}
```

But when I run the function, it crashed and show message below:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSSet initWithArray:range:copyItems:]: array argument is not an NSArray'
```

I also try to assign word to definition like :`definition.word = word`

But it appear the same crash message.

However, I can assign NSSet to word.definitons like this:

```
let definitionSet = NSSet(array: definitions)
    word.definitions = definitionSet
```

But this method will not let me append object...

Also, my other managedObject can use this kind of function`self.mutableSetValueForKey` to addObject. So I don't know where did it go wrong.

EDIT:

I'm trying to removeObject :

```
func removeDefinition(definition: MODefinition) {

    let muSet = self.mutableSetValueForKey("definitions")
    muSet.removeObject(definition)

}
```

And It shows

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSSingleObjectSetI objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I'd trying to implement on other objects, but only this object can't work.

What should I check for this problem, I'm really stuck now.

EDIT2 :

I add the new relationship to test if the problem is due to the relationship.

[image]

So, I added the test relationship.

And.... It work...

Although, I still don't know the reason, I can run normally now.

Answer (score 0):

i'm also new to ios.hope this will help you.

make  **NSManaged** in Moword class.
like:

> @NSManaged var word: NSSet?

and then  make **NSMutableSet** object

> let wordMutableSet = NSMutableSet()

and every time create new object of MoDefination

```
let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("MoDeination", inManagedObjectContext: Utilities.getAppManagedContext())

let obj = MoDefination(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: Utilities.getAppManagedContext())
```

wordMutableSet.addObject(obj)

and add it now in Moword object
    Moword entity1 =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Moword", inManagedObjectContext: Utilities.getAppManagedContext())

```
let obj = Moword(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: Utilities.getAppManagedContext())
obj?.scores = wordMutableSet
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, But my question is to modify the definitions(NSSet), which has a method to get the mutableSet to modify `mutableSetValueForKey("definitions")`.  My question is that, other object can use this way to do it, but only this class can't. And I found out that after I recreate a relationship, I can then use the way to modify. So, in my opinion, maybe the KVO issue about the "definitions", because I've change the MOWord.definitions relationship before, therefore I'm wondering if there some thing I misuse.